# How do I mark on a figure's spectrogram?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, spectrogram

Using a figure to create a new one, then spectrogram to plot on it, how do I mark a certain point on the existing figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hold feature:

`hold on`

This way, you can make another plot and it will overlay the spectrogram.

An example (you probably didn't see your marker because it wasn't large enough):

```
>> t=0:0.001:2;                    % 2 secs @ 1kHz sample rate  
>> y=chirp(t,100,1,200,'q');       % Start @ 100Hz, cross 200Hz at t=1sec   
>> spectrogram(y,128,120,128,1E3); % Display the spectrogram
>> hold on
>> plot(200,1,'bx','MarkerSize',20,'LineWidth',20); %Overlay a large, blue X
```

Comment: I tried it, for example
hold on;
plot(x,y,'bo');
and it didn't show on the plot

Comment: @Izhak Please see my above edit. It is likely that you didn't make your marker large/thick enough to see it.

Comment: Still nothing. But if I plot an asterisk first then use hold on; and plot spectrogram, the asterisk shows, and plotting more markers works well as you said. bug?

Comment: @Izhak That's pretty strange. The order in which you plot shouldn't matter when using this feature. Maybe you're plotting your spectrogram in some odd way? Either way, glad it worked.

Comment: @Izhak This is probably because of your 3-D renderer (OpenGL or zbuffer) which draws the spectrogram. Use `set(gcf, 'renderer', 'painters')` to use a simpler renderer that should plot layers properly.